# SQL - join tables on multiple columns

Tags: sql, join, multiple-columns

I want to join few tables:

```
table1:
A     B_key    B_version    C      D
123    abc        1         ccc    11  
123    abc        2         ddd    11
456    dfg        1         rrr    22
789    vvv        1                55

table2:
A     E   F 
123   s   5 
456   r   
111   t   2

table3:
B_key   B_version   G
abc        1        aa
abc        1        bb
abc        2        aa
abc        2        cc
dfg        1        aa
```

so the result would look like this:

```
A      B_key B_version       C      D    E       F    G
123    abc        1         ccc    11    s       5    aa
123    abc        1         ccc    11    s       5    bb
123    abc        2         ddd    11    s       5    aa
123    abc        2         ddd    11    s       5    cc
456    dfg        1         rrr    22    r            aa
789    vvv        1                55
```

Version can go as high as 8.

IF I don't have A, B_key or B_version - the line is useless. Otherwise I need to keep all the information I do have.

In reality I have many more columns.

I've tried:

```
SELECT table1.A, table 1.B_key, table 1.B_version, table 1.C, table 1.D,
       table2.E, table2.F,
       table3.G
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
     ON table1.A = table2.A
LEFT JOIN table3
     ON table1.B_key = table3.B_key AND
        table1.B_version = table3.B_version
```

and the same with FULL JOIN.

It ends up the same: for every B_key only the highest B_version is kept, while the others disappear.

How can I avoid loosing information?

Comment: Your question is not clear until you posted what you've actually tried!

Comment: lastly added query already works as intended, and gives the desired result. Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7508e7caa059609f936d62a093fb9381) .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all the `b_key`s and `b_version`s from `table1` and `table3`.  Then you want to bring in the other data.  That suggests left joins

```
select . . .
from ((select B_key, B_version 
       from table1
      ) union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      ( select B_key, B_version  
       from table3
      )
     ) bb left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.b_key = bb.b_key and
        t1.b_version = bb.b_version left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.a = t1.a left join
     table3 t3
     on t1.b_key = bb.b_key and
        t1.b_version = bb.b_version;
```

Comment: I tried to implement as you suggested, but abb doesn't have A in it.

Comment: @Masha . . . It did when I started.  I adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left joins among tables as below :

```
select t1.A, t1.B_key, t1.B_version, t1.C, t1.D, t2.E, t2.F, t3.G
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t2.A = t1.A
  left join table3 t3 on t3.B_key = t1.B_key and t3.B_version = t1.B_version
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7508e7caa059609f936d62a093fb9381)</kbd>

in order to bring also the rows for unmatched values for join conditions.